# Retrieve JSON Payload in Server Response from a Post Request with Ember Data

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I must be really missing something but I can't find a way to retrieve the json payload from a post request using ember data.  For example:

```
  var onSuccess = function(data) {
    //Want to get json payload from data
  };

  var onFail = function(data) {
    //Want to get json payload from data
  };

  // save model which sends a post request to the server
  model.save().then(onSuccess, onFail);
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Ember Data automatically processes the response from a POST and inserts and/or replaces any objects with matching IDs.  Objects are extracted from the payload automatically and placed in the store.  [Read about Ember Data's REST adapter and the conventions expected of your server](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/models/the-rest-adapter/)

Comment: following the Ember Data REST adapter convention exactly worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Great!  If you think my answer was the correct one, you can "accept" it (click the checkmark).  Thanks again.